# Formula for a Mixed effexts nested model example

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I would like to know how to properly formulate a statistical model.

We have  20 people.
Each individual has 2 implants, one made from material A and another one made with B.
We take 5 measures to every material and individual.

We  want to relate some Value (such as the composition or temperature) with the kind of material.

"A" is the same for every individual, and "B" too.

It would be similar to say:
We measure each person's leg 5 times and each person's arm 5 times and we want to find a relationship between leg's measures and arm's measures.

Using `lme4` how would you write the equation?

```
Value ~ material + (1|id)
```

or nested

```
Value ~ material + (1|id/material)
```

or

```
Value ~ material + (1|material/id)
```

The formula for any other software would be good as well.

I don't know if in this problem it's suitable to include the nested term because the material is not different for every individual, though it could evolve differently.

Comment: You interest is in the 'material' effect. It should not be in the random effects. I had other suggestions, since I don't think any of these are correct for this data structure. But these are statistical questions and not appropriate for SO. Suggesting migration.

Comment: Yes but I can take several measures for the same material.

Take a look to the example 3:
http://personality-project.org/r/r.anova.html#withinone
It uses Valence as a factor and also in the error term.

Comment: I don't doubt that you can model repeated measures, but I do not think you are modeling them correctly. The PersonalityProject citation you offer appears to be fairly old and uses `aov()`. You say you want to use `lmer`,  which is more "modern".